# How to implement radial motion blur by Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, graphics, computer-vision

I can find motion blur kernel in horizontal and vertical direction, e.g. this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/opencv-motion-blur-in-python/#:%7E:text=Motion%20blur%20is%20a%20specific,directed%20blur%20effect%20to%20images.&text=Applying%20motion%20blur%20to%20an,a%20filter%20across%20the%20image.).

However, how can I implement radial motion blur like following pictures? I can find this functionality in [Photoshop](https://shotkit.com/radial-blur/) etc. I cannot find any kernel reference in website. How can I implement it by python opencv? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Interesting question. You could probably do a few successive resizes (i.e. enlargements) and use `addWeighted()` to mangle the outputs together...

Comment: Mark is correct. That is how I did it in an Imagemagick script that I created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think OpenCV has something like this built-in, but DIPlib has: [`dip.AdaptiveGauss()`](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/nonlinear.html#dip-AdaptiveGauss-dip-Image-CL-dip-ImageConstRefArray-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-FloatArray-CL-dip-UnsignedArray-CL-dip-dfloat--dip-UnsignedArray-CL-dip-String-CL-dip-String-CL). It blurs the image with a different Gaussian at every pixel. One image indicates the orientation of the Gaussian, another one indicates the scaling.

This is how I replicated your blurred image:

```py
import diplib as dip

img = dip.ImageRead('rose.jpg')

scale = dip.CreateRadiusCoordinate(img.Sizes()) / 100
angle = dip.CreatePhiCoordinate(img.Sizes())
out = dip.AdaptiveGauss(img, [angle, scale], [1,5])

dip.Show(out)
```

[image: rose blurred with radial motion blur]

Disclaimer: I'm an author of DIPlib.